# Receive JSON Output from PHP in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am using this code in my PHP script:

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

and I get the following in my pages output:

```
[{"food_id":"1","food_description":"Free Range Egg","food_protein":"8"},{"food_id":"3","food_description":"Seeded Bread","food_protein":"6"}]
```

Can you please lead me the way on how I can receive the pages output in my Android Application and fit in in my object below? e.g.:

```
food.setFood_id(c.getInt("food_id"));
```

Comment: Check How to call API's from Android and then check how to parse json in android

Comment: See this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: food_id is string value how are you getting int value

Comment: i mean food.setFood_id(c.getString("food_id"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this..

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);// response is your json data which you are sending from php

JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("mMessage");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {


    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    food.setFood_id(jsonObj.getInt("food_id"));
}
```

and from php side you need to send data like this

```
public function get_data()
{
    $json_response = array();
    $sql_querry_arry = array(); // array filled with sql result
        $json_response['mMessage'] = $sql_querry_arry;

    echo json_encode($json_response);
}
```

Now receive output as a string and follow the steps i mention before

Comment: if you check my json object there is no name for the array or do you mean that my array name is the php $output? the (response) can be my inputstream like InputStream iStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

Comment: idk what do u mean...please post some code how you are receiving data from php

Comment: @Muhamman Summon posted a link please follow that link and you will get what you are looking for.....

Comment: I am not using any code for this this is why I need your help. I am getting the above output from my php page only and I want to get it to my android app.

Comment: I saw the link and actually that is the link that I am using but my result is from an sql query e.g. in a for loop i save my result in $output[]=$row; and then i encode it as Json